# Visiting the UK for 90 days - what are the visa/passport requirements?

Tags: visas, uk, us-citizens

My boyfriend is going to be staying with me for 90 days. He lives in the USA and I live in the UK. What does he need to do before travelling? Does he just need a valid passport?

I know that when visiting the US, you have to complete a ESTA form. Does he need to do anything like that for visiting the UK?

Comment: Is he a us citizen?

Comment: Yes, he is a US citizen

Comment: There is nothing like the ESTA in the UK (or other European countries incidentally).

Answer (score 2):

From [UK Border Agency](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/) :

> If you are coming to the UK for a short visit (up to 6 months), you
>   generally do not need a visa.
>
> However, you should bring documents with you to show our immigration
>   officers when you arrive at the UK border.
>
> The Visiting the UK section describes the different categories of
>   visitor visa, and lists the types of document that you may want to
>   provide. It also explains the conditions of your stay as a visitor.
>
> Although you do not need a visa, you may want to obtain one before you
>   travel (for example, if you have a criminal record or you have
>   previously been refused permission to enter the UK). And you will need
>   a visa if you want to come here in some categories of visitor (such as
>   a visitor for marriage or civil partnership). The Visiting the UK
>   section contains more information.

[See also](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/visiting/general/documents/):

> If you travel to the UK without a visa, you should bring them with you
>   so that you can show them to our officers at the border.
>
> You should provide as many relevant documents as you can to show that
>   you qualify for entry to the UK. If you do not provide them, we may
>   refuse your application.
>
> You must decide which documents will best support your application. We
>   advise you to consider providing documents that contain:
>
> - information about you
> - information about your finances and employment
> - your accommodation and travel details
> - information about your visit to the UK

Comment: I've looked on the website and it says..

you have enough money to support and accommodate yourself without working or help from public funds, or you and any dependants will be supported and accommodated by relatives or friends;

How much does he need to bring or prove? I work full time so I will be able to feed/cloth him etc

Comment: @SummeLoving from http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/visiting/sponsoringavisitor/documents/ :" If you will supply financial support and accommodation for your visitor, and/or you will pay for their travel to the UK, they will need to provide: copies of your bank or building society statements and payslips for the last 6 months; or a copy of your savings account book."

Comment: A return ticket and/or proof of his situation in the US are probably most useful (to show that he is actually visiting and not intent on staying illegally). I don't think border officers routinely check the rest but the point is that you can be refused entry if they are not convinced by your story (sponsorship and the like are most relevant to people who need to apply for a visa).

Comment: @Annoyed For long visits, a return ticket and proof of US citizenship might not be enough. "Sure, you have a return ticket but how do we know going to use it?"

Comment: @DavidRicherby I was not merely thinking about citizenship but a job, student registration, owning a business or house, etc. But you're right, there is always a possibility that it might not be enough (I don't think my comment suggests anything else, it's just that these things seem most useful). Now, if the border officers have reasons to doubt your intent to use your return ticket, I don't see why your girlfriend's payslips or any of the documents mentioned above should convince them otherwise. In fact, it's precisely in this case that documenting your situation in the US is most important.

Comment: @Annoyed OK, yes, those things would probably be enough because they indicate that the person would be giving up a lot if they didn't use the return half of the ticket.